# Intuition behind projective closure.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

Attached is a picture of a projective closure of the affine variety $\mathbb{V}(y - x^2)$. Using this, I am trying to form an intuition of how projective closures work in higher dimensions. It seems that the graph extends to infinity in both $x$ and $y$ directions, however, we only add a point at infinity in the $y$ direction for its projective closure. This makes sense(?) as the graph seems to extend in the $y$ direction faster than the $x$ direction. This also makes sense in terms of the degree: $x$ has a higher degree in the equation hence, we need to multiply a $z$ to $y$ in order to homogenize and thus $[0:1:0]$ is a point we add to its closure defined by the vanishing of $zy - x^2$. But the higher degree of $x$ in $y - x^2$ also means that by comparing partials, the graph does indeed increase faster in the $y$ direction.

Now here is where I am confused. Suppose we have a variety in $\mathbb{A}^3$ defined by the vanishing of both $y - x^2$ and $z - xy$. This is a twisted cubic consisting of all triples $\{(\lambda, \lambda^2, \lambda^3)\}.$ The text I am reading states that the vanishing of the homogenized ideal $(wy -x^2, wz - xy)$ consists of the projective closure as well as the line defined by the vanishing of $w$ and $x.$

Here are some questions.

1. Is the projective closure of any affine variety just adding points at infinity? Hence just adding a finite number of elements of projective space to the affine variety?
2. In the projective closure of the twisted cubic, are we just adding a point at infinity pointing in the $y$ direction as well as a point at infinity pointing in the $z$ direction? If this is true, is my intuition about the slowest direction not getting a point at infinity correct? At each point in the twisted cubic, the $x$ direction grows the slowest.... Does this method determine which points get added to the affine variety to form its projective closure?

It seems that determining the points of the form $[a_1: \ldots : a_{n + 1}]$ (for which all but one coordinate is 0) that are included in the variety defined by the homogenization of our ideal gives us the same result. These two methods are also closely linked together as described above. Sorry if this is a lot of words that mean very little. I just want to develop my intuition.

Comment: In general the projective closure of a variety in $\Bbb A^n$ involves adding an subvariety of the "points at infinity", not just a finite number of points. For example, let $X$ be a plane in $\Bbb A^3$. The projective closure requires the addition of a $\Bbb P^1$ within the "points at infinity" in $\Bbb P^3$.

Comment: You do not merely add *points* at infinity when taking projective closure. For example, $\mathbb{P}^2$ is the projective closure of $\mathbb{A}^2$. $\mathbb{P}^2$ is an $\mathbb{A}^2$ (identified with $[x:y:1]$) plus a "$\mathbb{P}^1$ at infinity" (identified with $[x:y:0]$). This $\mathbb{P}^1$ itself is already an $\mathbb{A}^1$ with a point at infinity.

Comment: Is there an example where we add infinite number of points when the variety we take is not the entire affine space? I cannot think of say a curve or a surface in $\mathbb{A}^3$ that requires an infinite number of added points for its projective closure.

Comment: The projective closure should have the same dimension as the original variety. If you start with a curve, its projective closure will be of dimension $1$, and thus there will only be a finite number of added points. With a surface however, the projective closure can add more than a point, try for instance computing the projective closure of a surface defined by a single homogeneous polynomial: its homogeneization will not involve the "new coordinate" in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and so there will be a lot of new points (all the $[x:y:z:w]$ for $x,y,z$ already solutions of the polynomial).